# Display a random image from array in ImageView after 5000 milliseconds

Tags: java, random, imageview

I have an array of strings that displays a random text result in a `TextView` after a button is pressed and after 5000 milliseconds. What I am trying to achieve is to have an array of images instead of text and so would like a random image showing in an `ImageView` after the 5000 milliseconds.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView thumbPrint;
    private TextView result;
    private AnimationDrawable thumbAnimation;
    private String[] moodResults;
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        moodResults = new String[]{
            "result a",
            "result b",
            "result c",
            "result d",
            "result e",
            "result f"
        };

        thumbPrint = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbPrint);
        thumbPrint.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thumb_animation);
        thumbAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)thumbPrint.getBackground();

        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultText);

        thumbPrint.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                thumbAnimation.start();
                showResult();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void showResult(){
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int rand = (int)(Math.random()* moodResults.length);
                result.setText(moodResults[rand]);
                //stop animation
                thumbAnimation.stop();
            }
        };

        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: the images will be stored in drawable folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement it this way:

These variables are declared in MainActivity. They can be seperately initialized inside `onCreate()`

```
 final int[] imageIds= {
            R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, ...}; // This is your array with resource id of each image
 Random r = new Random();
 Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

This is the refactored code for `showResult()`:

```
public void showResult(){
            mRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int rand = (int)(Math.random()* moodResults.length);
                    result.setText(moodResults[rand]);
                    int randomInt = r.nextInt(imageIds.length);
                    thumbprint.setBackgroundResource(imageIds[randomInt]); //thumbprint is your Imageview
                    //stop animation
                    thumbAnimation.stop();
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000);//This causes hanlder to called again in 5 seconds
                }
            };

            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000); //Here handler is called the first time; the code in mRunnable will execute after 5 seconds 
        }
```

Comment: would i link this to the onClick method for button press? or just replace the existing array of text

Comment: If you don't need the TextView and you were just experimenting, then remove it as  well as the String array. If you want to show both random image with its description as text, initialize the both the String and int array together and put everything else where you want the image to be changed.

Comment: seems to be giving me an error under (imageIds.length) method a call expected

Comment: I've made some changes. use imageIds.length instead.

Comment: tried the new code, the app runs but the image is there constantly, i would like the random image to show after the 5000 miliseconds and animation

Comment: change the ImageView background inside the handler. Since it is running at an interval of 5000 millis, this should be happening then.

Comment: would i have to create a new Runnable? struggling to put imageview inside the current runnable! i am new to android development so sorry in advance!

Comment: No, just the runnable you're already using in the method showresult.

Comment: i place it in the handler like imageIds.postdelayed(mRunnable,5000);

Comment: thank you for this, however it wont let me use the imageView, my imageview id is resultImageView and when i remove thumbprint and place in resultImageView it gives red error

Comment: my bad, was beaten by a curly brace, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array of strings with images paths and choose a random path and show that image.

Comment: tried that but cant seem to get it to work, i put an array of images in place of the array of string text,but just not working for me! to get it to show random image after the 5000 miliseconds and after the animation is what i am finding difficult